# how to hide a view in all recyclerview row after button clicked?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I want to create a recycler view like below images, when the user clicks on radio Button seek bar visible and radio button invisible in all recycler view's items.
[brfore click image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATQ4W.png) and [after click image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnKcW.png)
this is my Recycler view adapter code:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final VoteRvViewHolder voteRvViewHolder, final int i) {

    final VoteRecyclerViewDataModel dataModel = voteRecyclerViewDataModels.get(i);
    voteRvViewHolder.optionContent.setText(dataModel.getOptionContent());
    voteRvViewHolder.optionPercent.setText(dataModel.getPercentOption());
    voteRvViewHolder.seekbar.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(dataModel.getPercentOption()));
    voteRvViewHolder.seekbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    voteRvViewHolder.optionPercent.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    voteRvViewHolder.radioBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (voteOptionClickListener != null) {
                if (i != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    if (wholeView != null) {
                        voteOptionClickListener.OnVoteOprionClick(wholeView, voteRecyclerViewDataModels.get(i), i);
                        voteRvViewHolder.seekbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        voteRvViewHolder.optionPercent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Problem is when I click on one of the radio button that row is changed I want all rows changed

Comment: may you share your code?
you can use `radioButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);` and `seekbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

Comment: I add codes, check it, please!

Comment: you need a boolean variable in your `voteRecyclerViewDataModels` like`visibilityItem` , `i` variable in `onBindViewHolder` is your item `position`, I think you need a for loop in `radioBtn.setOnClickListener`, then set false to `visibilityItem` variable for all of your items.
now in your code check if `visibilityItem` is true then show `radioButton` else hide it and sho `seekbar.`

Answer (score 1):

Maintain click state in data list of Recycler view using variable and put layout(seekbar/ radio button) in Frame layout.On radio button click change the variable in data list .On the basis of that variable you can display radio button/Seekbar in onBindView holder.